# Php require() - Realtive paths

Tags: html, data-structures, directory, relative-path

Here's sort of a silly question.  When File A does an include() of file B, and file B does an include of file C, and all the the paths are relative, are the 'child' references relative to their own path, or to the 'master' file (file A) in which they're included?

for example:

**directory structure**

> **Root**
>
> header.html (File B)
>
> > **/images** / logo.png (File C)
> >
> > **/site** / index.php (File A)

index.php contains:
   include('../header.html');

header.html contains:
   include('images/logo.png');

Will this work?  Or since index.php is the 'master' file, will it try to look for 'images' within the 'sites' folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are always relative to the "master" file. Included files are treated as "injections" of source code into the main script, so they behave as if they were inside the main script.

To address something relative to the actual current file, use the `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` constants that always point to the file they're in.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `__DIR__` (I integrated that part shamelessly into my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The paths are relative to the working directory. The initial working directory is the directory that contains the PHP file that was executed directly in response to the HTTP request (i.e. what you called *master* file.).

An `include` does not change the working directory, but it can be changed manually by calling [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php). However I advice against changing the working directory solely for the sake of an `include`.

Better use [set_include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) or the corresponding configuration option or, as Pekka suggested, use `__DIR__` to construct a filename relative to the directory of the current file.

Comment: +1 for the reminder that the "working directory" principle is still valid in PHP